# Unable to use full resolution of a 4k monitor using Digital Port

Tags: display-resolution, hdmi, wayland, displayport

I recently upgraded my system with a Ryzen 9 7900 with integrated radeon graphics and the motherboard has two video ports: HDMI and DP.

When I connect my 4K monitor (Samsung LU28E590DS) on the HDMI port everything works perfectly.

Instead when I connect it using the DP port the maximum available resolution is 2K. After many many tries and reboots once it happened ubuntu allowed me to use 4K resolution, but only at 30hz (unusable).

Things I tried, to know:

- The Display Port with the same monitor works correctly under windows 10
- I already changed the cable to make some tests
- I tried both with wayland and X11
- I tried updating the kernel to version 6.4 instead of the stock 6.2 provided with Ubunti 23.04 Lunar)
- With a 4K monitor LG 32UN500 the problem is the same
- With another 4K monitor, LG 24GN53A, it works correctly

This problem is really blocking for me and I've no clue how to solve it!